# Control may reach end of non-void function - when using Apple's code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am getting the following warning:

> Control may reach end of non-void function

when using some code from developer.apple.com:

[Apple's code for Taking Pictures and Movies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html)

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate
{
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) || (delegate == nil) || (controller == nil)) return NO;

    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
    [controller presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: the functions is declared to return `BOOL` and you have to return a `BOOL`

Comment: Thanks to all - fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return a BOOL value in your function in order to get rid of the warning
After the line just call

```
 [controller presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
 return YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning any value if the "IF condition" is not satisfied.

add a:-

```
return YES; // after controller presentViewController statement
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed a `return YES`; line at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write/ put  `return YES;` at end of your function. ...`- (BOOL) startCameraCon.......`